# Faster version/replacement of `Select[]`

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following code:

```
atime = AbsoluteTiming;
{a, b, n} = {2, 1, 3000};
pts = RandomReal[{-a, a}, {3/2 n, 2}]; // atime
k = b/a; // atime
pts = Map[{#[[1]], k #[[2]]} &, pts]; // atime
pts = Select[pts, (#[[1]]^2/a^2 + #[[2]]^2/b^2 <= 1) &]; // atime
pts = Take[pts, n]; // atime
Graphics[pts // Point] // atime 
Clear[a, b, n, pts, k]
```

which produces this:

[image]

We see that almost all the time here was spent on `Select[]`. Is there a faster version/replacement of `Select[]`? (I am aware of `RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, {a, b}], n]`, but the point of this question is about a faster version of `Select[]`.)

Comment: `pts = Pick[pts, UnitStep[1 - Total[Transpose[pts^2]/{a^2, b^2}]], 1];`

Comment: ciao's version is faster, but `Pick[pts, RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}, {a, b}], pts]]` is also quite speedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-a, a}, {3/2 n, 2}];

pts1 = Pick[pts, UnitStep[1 - (pts^2 .( 1/{a, b}^2))], 1]; //  atime // First
```

> ```
>  0.0002691
> ```

```
pts2 = Select[pts, (#[[1]]^2/a^2 + #[[2]]^2/b^2 <= 1) &]; // atime // First
```

> ```
>  0.0346072
> ```

```
pts1 == pts2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am wondering why `Pick` is so much faster than `Select`.

Comment: @IosifPinelis - it isn't any mystery, `Select[list, func]` will need to evaluate `func` on *every element* of `list`.  But any of the `Pick` solutions given here are evaluating a test function on `list` in a single evaluation.